# collectstatic refers to wrong directory

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I got a problem that I can't seem to to find the root cause for.

When I run the 'collectstatic' command I get error file not found. I can see it tries to put files in wrong directory.

First after running the command I get this question

> You have requested to collect static files at the destination location
>   as specified in your settings:
>
> ```
> /var/www/projects/foobar/foobar/static
> ```

Which is right. But I get this error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   '/var/www/projects/foobar/foobar/foobar/static'

Thats one dir of 'foobar' to much.

This is my settings for the production:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/www/projects/foobar/foobar/media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/projects/foobar/foobar/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

How come it adds an extra dir of 'foobar'?

Answer (score 1):

The path you have specified in the STATIC_ROOT may be incorrect, using os.path.join can resolve this error since it is a better approach of specifying the path relative to the project directory.

Please make these following changes in your code:

> STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
>
> STATIC_URL = '/static/'

and then try to run your project again. I will suggest making the same changes for MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL as well, as it a better coding practice.